# How to set up Supervisor and Laravel Horizon on Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, amazon-ecs, supervisord

I have successfully deployed a laravel application with horizon installed to AWS ECS. However horizon has remained **Inactive** and I am stuck trying to get it to work as my emails are getting queued and never sent. This is my docker file

```
FROM php:8.1.4-fpm-alpine3.14

RUN apk update

RUN apk add --no-cache git libzip-dev zip unzip php8-exif supervisor

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis; \
    curl -fsSL https://pecl.php.net/get/redis --ipv4 | tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/redis" --strip 1; \
    docker-php-ext-install redis;

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip exif \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY horizon.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/horizon.conf

COPY . .

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN composer install --ignore-platform-req=ext-pcntl

RUN chmod 544 startup.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]

ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
```

I created a supervisord.conf file with this content in it

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

a horizon.conf file with its content below

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/html/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

and this is what my startup script `startup.sh` looks like

```
#!/bin/sh

php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed

php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache

php artisan horizon
php artisan queue:restart

php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

I am not exactly very knowledgable with supervisor on containers so I need help figuring out why I am not able to get horizon to be active and fix it.

Comment: It's usually a better practice to run multiple containers with a single process per container.  In any case a container only runs a single command, and the `CMD` string `supervisord` is passed as an argument to the `ENTRYPOINT` script `startup.sh`; do you need to end that script with `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`, instead of unconditionally running `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Are you suggesting I move the `supervisord` command to my `startup.sh` file?

Comment: My main suggestion would be to run Horizon and the main application in separate containers, and remove Supervisord from this stack entirely.

Comment: @DavidMaze I get your suggestion now. I will give it a try